# dist() returns different result compared to the console.log

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am making a program that creates and moves some dots, then each dot is connected to x closest dots to it. My problem is that lines are created in the wrong place, or not all which is weird. Here is my code:

```js
var numPoints = 10;
var connections = 3;
var points = [];
var noiseT = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(displayWidth, displayHeight);
  // creating points and settings for the random movement
  for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
    var tempNoiseX = random(-50, 50);
    var tempNoiseY = random(-50, 50);
    var tempNoiseXplus = random(-0.002, 0.002);
    var tempNoiseYplus = random(-0.002, 0.002);
    noiseT.push([tempNoiseX, tempNoiseY, tempNoiseXplus, tempNoiseYplus]);
    var tempX = width * noise(noiseT[i][0]);
    var tempY = height * noise(noiseT[i][1]);
    points.push([tempX, tempY]);
  }
  frameRate(60);
  stroke(0,0,255);
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  // moving the points
  for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
    points[i][0] = width * noise(noiseT[i][0]) * 1.2;
    points[i][1] = height * noise(noiseT[i][1]) * 1.2;
  }

  // calculate the distance between all the points
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var distance = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < numPoints; j++) {
      var startX = points[i][0];
      var startY = points[i][1];
      var endX = points[j][0];
      var endY = points[j][1];
      var tempDistance = dist(startX, startX, endX, endY);
      distance[tempDistance] = [endX, endY];
    }

    var tempKeys = Object.values(Object.keys(distance)).sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b
    });
    // drawing lines
    for (var c = 0; c < connections; c++) {
      line(points[i][0], points[i][1], distance[tempKeys[c]][0], distance[tempKeys[c]][1]);
    }
  }

  // adding noise
  for (var i = 0; i < noiseT.length; i++) {
    noiseT[i][0] += noiseT[i][2];
    noiseT[i][1] += noiseT[i][3];
  }
  // cehcking the borders
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    if (points[i][0] >= width) {
      points[i][0] = width;
    } else if (points[i][0] <= 0) {
      points[i][0] = 0;
    }
    if (points[i][1] >= height) {
      points[i][1] = height;
    } else if (points[i][1] <= 0) {
      points[i][1] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

I already tried making the lines at different points and how I make them, all resulting in the same issue. (the code is zoomed out a lot by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your code in `dist(startX, startX, endX, endY)`, `startX` is twice, but `startY` is missing. It has to be:

```
var tempDistance = dist(startX, startY, endX, endY);
```

The first dot in the list is the dot itself, because it has distance 0. So the closest 3 dots, except the dot itself are the dots with the indices 1, 2 and 3:

```
for (var c = 1; c <= connections; c++) {
  line(points[i][0], points[i][1], distance[tempKeys[c]][0], distance[tempKeys[c]][1]);
}
```

```js
var numPoints = 10;
var connections = 3;
var points = [];
var noiseT = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(innerWidth, innerHeight);
  // creating points and settings for the random movement
  for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
    var tempNoiseX = random(-50, 50);
    var tempNoiseY = random(-50, 50);
    var tempNoiseXplus = random(-0.002, 0.002);
    var tempNoiseYplus = random(-0.002, 0.002);
    noiseT.push([tempNoiseX, tempNoiseY, tempNoiseXplus, tempNoiseYplus]);
    var tempX = width * noise(noiseT[i][0]);
    var tempY = height * noise(noiseT[i][1]);
    points.push([tempX, tempY]);
  }
  frameRate(60);
  stroke(0,0,255);
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  // moving the points
  for (var i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
    points[i][0] = width * noise(noiseT[i][0]) * 1.2;
    points[i][1] = height * noise(noiseT[i][1]) * 1.2;
  }

  // calculate the distance between all the points
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var distance = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < numPoints; j++) {
      var startX = points[i][0];
      var startY = points[i][1];
      var endX = points[j][0];
      var endY = points[j][1];
      var tempDistance = dist(startX, startY, endX, endY);
      distance[tempDistance] = [endX, endY];
    }

    var tempKeys = Object.values(Object.keys(distance)).sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b
    });
    // drawing lines
    for (var c = 1; c <= connections; c++) {
      line(points[i][0], points[i][1], distance[tempKeys[c]][0], distance[tempKeys[c]][1]);
    }
  }

  // adding noise
  for (var i = 0; i < noiseT.length; i++) {
    noiseT[i][0] += noiseT[i][2];
    noiseT[i][1] += noiseT[i][3];
  }
  // cehcking the borders
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    if (points[i][0] >= width) {
      points[i][0] = width;
    } else if (points[i][0] <= 0) {
      points[i][0] = 0;
    }
    if (points[i][1] >= height) {
      points[i][1] = height;
    } else if (points[i][1] <= 0) {
      points[i][1] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel kind of stupid for missing that typo, maybe because I focused too much on one specific bit I already knew about the second thing you mentioned, I had a comment saying to add one to the global variable but I removed it.